# Prove that $E(N_t) = \frac{t}{E(Y_1)}$ for a renewal process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

Given a sequence $Y_i$ of i.i.d random variables with finite mean, representing the interarrival times.
Define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ to be the arrival times, and $N_t = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \bf{1}_{\{S_n \le t\}}$ denoting the number of arrivals in the interval $[0,t]$.

Prove that $E(N_t) = \frac{t}{E(Y_1)}$

It seems like this should be immediate from the definitions, but I can't seem to prove it.

Comment: It's true only asymptotically, for large $t$, except in case the $Y_i$ have an exponential distribution. In that case, use the fact that $N_t$ has the Poisson distribution with mean $1/E(Y_1)$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Are you sure it's only asymptotically true? Do you have an example where it doesn't hold?

Comment: No example is possible. One can show, by computing Laplace transforms, that if $E(N_t) = t/E(Y_1)$ for all $t>0$, the $Y_1$ has an exponential distribution. (And conversely.)

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thank you. I realize now that a simple counter example is taking $Y_i = 1$. This leads to $E(N_t)= \left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor $. I'm new, should I delete the question? Or answer with the my counter example?

Comment: I'd leave it.  It's a natural conjecture, and it's good to know when plausible guesses are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

A simple counter example: take $Y_i=1$ for all $i$. This leads to $E(N_t)=⌊t⌋$.